# How can I retrieve a cookie (token) from a Microsoft sign-in event and store it in my app

Tags: oracle, azure, http, flutter, single-sign-on

This is my goal:

[Client is accessing Oracle Access Management federated through Microsoft Azure]

1 - Launch a webview or browser to allow the user to sign in to their Microsoft account then automatically redirect the user back to the app on a successful login

2 - Retrieve a cookie (token) from Oracle WebSSO and save it to the device in order to use it for future HTTP requests without the need for the user to authenticate again (is this the best method?)

Basically I'm trying to figure out how Oracle handles SSO and how I can integrate that into a Flutter app specifically. I believe I need to grab the OAMAuthnCookie and/or OAM_ID cookie.

Thank you.